# Map.lookup is defined to work within any monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, option-type

So I am learning some Haskell, and while reading "Monad Transformers Step by Step" by Martin Grabmüller I came across to the following example. 
[image: excerpt from the paper]

These are the imports used in the given code.

```
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

I don't really understand how the line `eval1 env (Var n) = Map.lookup n env` should work. In the explanation it is written that the function `Map.lookup` works with every monad, while the return type is clearly defined as `Maybe a`

```
Map.lookup :: Ord k => k -> Map.Map k a -> Maybe a
```

Neither I am able to compile the code,nor I understand the explanation. So am I missing something? Can anyone give a better explanation for the code?

P.S. Link to the paper 
https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/scravy/realworldhaskell/materialien/monad-transformers-step-by-step.pdf

Comment: That paper was written back in 2006, and at that time `lookup` was [indeed defined like this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html)

Comment: oh thanks, such a simple explanation

Comment: I really, really wish one of the authors would write an update. There are now a few different things in that (truly excellent) tutorial that don't quite work as written in modern Haskell.

Comment: You can recover the old behaviour with a wrapper like `mapLookup k m = case Map.lookup k m of { Just v -> pure v; Nothing -> fail "Data.Map.lookup: Key not found" }`—in pointfree form: `mapLookup = fmap (maybe (fail "…") pure) . Map.lookup`.

Comment: @JonPurdy, that will very soon require a (long-overdue) shift from `Monad` to `MonadFail`.

Comment: @JonPurdy (and dfeuer): I have added the compatibility wrapper to my answer to the target question.

Comment: @dfuer it already does require `MonadFail`, since GHC 8.6.1